# Can I push a Newsstand notification with apn_on_rails?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails-3, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, newsstand-kit

Is there any way using [apn_on_rails](https://github.com/timsu/apn_on_rails) to push Newsstand notification? i.e. Push this kind of payload:

```
{"aps": {"badge": 1,"content-available":"1"} }
```

At the moment [I can see](http://yekmer.posterous.com/how-to-send-iphone-push-notifications-in-rail) that I can push notification with badge, sound, and alerts.

I'm sure it wouldn't be hard to modify apn_on_rails itself if it turns out it doesn't do it yet. There are so many branches of apn_on_rails, I am using [this one](https://github.com/timsu/apn_on_rails) at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `APN::Notification` class has a [`custom_properties`](https://github.com/timsu/apn_on_rails/blob/master/lib/apn_on_rails/app/models/apn/notification.rb#L20) property that you use to include any generic data in the push notification. Using your payload as an example, you would do something like this:

```
apn = APN::Notification.new
apn.badge = 1
apn.custom_properties = {"content-available" => 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

Grocer also supports Newsstand notifications. https://github.com/grocer/grocer#newsstand-notifications

```
notification = Grocer::NewsstandNotification.new(device_token: "...")
# Generates a JSON payload like:
# {"aps": {"content-available": 1}}
```